# I'm having issues using Hyperactive library in results

Tags: conv-neural-network, hyperparameters

I use the hyperactive library for hyperparameter optimization on CNN, but when I run the code below it produces an error.

```
search_data = hyper.results(model)
search_data
```

[results of running coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XHmG.png)

please help me find a solution to this problem

please help me find a solution to this problem